# Multiply and divide Series making nans stay as nans

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 series:

```
value_column = pd.Series([1,np.NaN,3,4,5,6])
b = pd.Series([1,2,3,np.NaN,5,np.NaN])
c = pd.Series([1,2,3,np.NaN,5,np.NaN])
```

If I multiply and divide them like this, I get:

```
Result = value_column.multiply(b, fill_value=1).divide(c, fill_value=1)
Result = pd.Series([1,1,3,4,5,6])
```

Note in the result above, the second value is 1 instead of np.NaN.
Below, the result I need.

```
Result_I_need = pd.Series([1,np.NaN,3,4,5,6])
```

One way to get the result I need is by doing the operation and then adding the line:

```
Result_I_need = np.where(value_column.isna(), np.NaN, Result_I_need)
```

but it seems not very professional. How can I do this? NOTE: The fill_value=1 parameters are in use for other combination of values.

Comment: dont use fill_value=1 and you will get np.NaN

Comment: @KlemenKoleša This is a vanilla example. I need those  fill_value=1 for my application.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC add `combine_first`

```
value_column.mul(b.div(c,fill_value=1)).combine_first(value_column)
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Or zip it in one-line using `where` rather than `np.where`

```
value_column.where(value_column.isna(),value_column.mul(b.div(c,fill_value=1),fill_value=1))
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `fillna` to `b`, `c` before calculation:

```
value_column * b.fillna(1) / c.fillna(1)

Out[1058]:
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    6.0
dtype: float64
```